# $! not being set to the PID of a > >(...) process substitution used with an external command

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

Bash 4.4.19(1)-release

I have below a simple script which is the basis for a logging app. 
For various reasons I had to use process substitution.

The `runner` is the heart of the app and since process substitution is asynchronous, I have managed to get it to a good degree of coherence by the `while` loop. It works perfectly.

Unfortunately I found a case where it will not work: when I execute '`bash <filename> <function>`'

So we need 2 files to reproduce.

**Requirement:**

1. Why does this happen?
2. How to modify my while loop to accommodate similar cases?

Simplified script is:

`test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

2sub() {
local in=$(cat); echo -e "$in";
}   
runner () {
 "${@}" 1> >(2sub)
 while [ -e /proc/$! ]; do sleep 0.1; done     # <<< LOOP WAIT FOR $!
}
remotesub() {
 bash ./test2.sh remotesub2
}

echo -e "running\n"; 
    runner bash ./test2.sh remotesub2 # LOOPS
    # runner remotesub # A POSSIBLE BYPASS/SOLUTION? But why?
echo -e "done!\n"
```

`test2.sh`

```
     remotesub2() {
         echo -e "'${BASH_VERSION}'"
         return 0
     }

     "$@"
```

**Bypass:**

As you can see from the script, there is a bypass for the problem, by including `bash <filename> <function>` inside a function, and *passing the function* to the `runner`. Why this works and not the direct way, I am sure somebody here knows.

Please shed some light on this issue and if there are some better ways to do the waiting loop in order to cover these cases.

**Solution:**

The best solution is what mosvy suggested. Thank you.
Using  `{ "${@}"; }` removes the need to package the commands in separate small functions which is a pain. Also after many hours of testing with my larger code, I came to the conclusion that careful killing of sub-processes makes this `while [ -e /proc/$! ]; do sleep 0.1; done` unnecessary. That line was replaced with `wait $!;`

Comment: Which bash version are you using?

Comment: 4.4.19(1)-release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you exactly, you're wondering why `$!` will be set to the PID of a process run inside `>(...)` only when that is part of the command line of a built-in command or function, but not when it's part of the command line of an external command.

Simplified example:

```
$ bash -c 'true > >(echo in=$BASHPID; sleep .1); echo psubst=$!'
psubst=12392
in=12392

$ bash -c '/bin/true > >(echo in=$BASHPID; sleep .1); echo psubst=$!'
in=12751
psubst=
```

That happens because in the case where an external command is used `bash` will fork a separate process to run it in, and the process running inside the `>(...)` will be run as a child of that process, and so as a *grand*child of your script, completely outside of its control.

By the time the external command terminates, its child (if still running) will be adopted by pid 1 (init), and so any link that could still be used to retrieve its PID from your script is broken.

A workaround may be to use a wrapper function which will cause all the process substitutions from its command line to be run as children of your script, so their PIDs could be retrieved via `pgrep -P "$$"`.

Also, putting the external command in `{...}` block and redirecting the ouput of the block also seems to work:

```
$ bash -c 'func(){ /bin/true; }; func > >(echo in=$BASHPID; sleep .1); echo psubst=$!'
in=3574
psubst=3574
$  bash -c '{ /bin/true; } > >(echo in=$BASHPID; sleep .1); echo psubst=$!'
in=3435
psubst=3435
```

Both workarounds rely on the way the current implementation works; eg. `bash` may decide one day to optimize away trivial group commands or functions, breaking these assumptions.

Notice that `$!` being set to the PID from the last process substitution is an undocumented feature, which also does not work in other shells than `bash`.

Comment: so my 'POSSIBLE BYPASS/SOLUTION' mentioned in the script is the only solution to this issue?

Comment: I guess so. Using a function wrapper will make sure that the subshell from the process substitution will be a child of your script.

Comment: I'll update this answer when I get time (or remove it ;-)). In the meanwhile, `wait $!` or `wait $(pgrep -P $$)` would be a better idea than your loop (the latter since I'm not sure that `$!` is documented anywhere to be also set to the pid of a process substitution)

Comment: perfect thanks for taking the time

Comment: See... I am even pioneering in areas you never knew existed!! ))

Comment: is there maybe a way to use something like this  "${${@}}" 1> >(2sub) to force execution within a local context? effectively bringing the external function and wrapping it inside a local function all in one go?

Comment: No, only `zsh` has *something like* anonymous functions (lambdas): `(){ echo "$@"; } 1 2 3`. But you can probably try redirecting the output of a whole `{ ... }` block, as in: `{ "$@"; } > >(2sub)`.