# How to capture stderr of function that modifies current environment?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, environment-variables, stderr

The `module` function of the [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/)<sup>1</sup> package does its work by modifying various environment variables of the *current* shell process.

Unfortunately, this function returns 0 whether it succeeds or not<sup>2</sup>, which makes it difficult for a client script to respond appropriately to failures.

I would like to implement a function wrapper `mymodule` around `module` that passes all its arguments straight through to `module`, and properly returns a non-zero value if `module` fails.

The only way that `mymodule` can detect whether `module` failed is to inspect the output `module` function writes to stderr, if any.

The problem is that I can't come up with a reasonable way for `mymodule` to get this output without nullifying `module`'s actions.  More specifically, almost all the ways I can think of to capture `module`'s stderr into a variable entail running `module` in a child process, thus preventing it from doing its job (which requires modifying the current shell).

The one exception to the above would be to redirect `module`'s stderr to a temporary file, but I hate the idea of creating a file every time the `module` function runs.

Is there some way for `mymodule` to invoke `module` in the current environment and at the same time capture its stderr in a variable?

I am interested in answers for both `zsh` and `bash`.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Not to be confused with the [Lmod environment modules](https://lmod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package, which has a very similar interface.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> At least this is the case for the ancient version 3.2.9 that I must work with.  I have no control over this.</sup>

Comment: Why is creating a temp file so bad? Is spawning an extra process really preferable? The shell may already create temporary files behind your back in order to implement such syntax as here-docs (`<<`) or here-strings (`<<<`). Anyway here is an example of trouble free use of tempfiles: `t=$(mktemp); exec 7<"$t" 8>"$t"; rm "$t"; ...; module 2>&8; case $(cat <&7) in ... esac`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Bash and zsh have [coprocesses](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Coprocesses) (unfortunately slightly different), which essentially wrap up [a `pipe` call](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html) and spawning a subprocess with both its standard input and standard output available to the calling shell. In essence they let the shell play both `x` and `y` in `x | cmd | y`, but with all of `x`, `y`, and `cmd` running from the current process and *not* in a pipeline execution environment.

That will let us run `module 2>&...` for some `...`, with `module` running from the current shell. If we use `cat` as our coprocess (i.e. `cmd`), it will just repeat everything straight back out again, and then we can read the output back into the current shell again with `y <&...` later on.

Another option is to redirect standard error into another background process and `wait` for its return code. I will address both below.

---

I'm going to use this fake `module` function to test with so that I can turn errors on and off at will. If modifies the current shell environment so that we can see it and outputs "err" to stderr; I'll be commenting that line in and out as needed:

```
module() {
        sleep 1
        FOO=$(date)
        echo err >&2
}
```

---

If I run a `cat` coprocess in Bash I can redirect `module`'s stderr into that, and read from `cat`'s stdout to do whatever I want:

```
coproc cat
module 2>&${COPROC[1]}
exec {COPROC[1]}>&-
if grep -q err <&${COPROC[0]}
then
        echo got an error
else
        echo no error
fi
```

In zsh it needs to be

```
module 2>&p
exec 4<&p
coproc :
if grep -q err <&4
```

in the middle instead.

In either case, I can both run the `module` command in the current shell and read from the error output there. A function could return within the `if` as normal.

Everything except `cat` is running from the current execution environment: FD redirections do *not* create independent environments the way pipelines do. We can `echo $FOO` at the end to check that, and see that the date has updated because `module` ran in the current environment.

---

Alternatively, the background process could just do all the work. This works in Bash:

```
exec 2> >( if grep -q . ; then exit 7 ; else exit 0 ; fi )
PID=$!
module
exec 2>&-
wait $PID
echo $?
```

The above will output either `7` or `0` according to what the subprocess at the top said — you can adjust to do whatever you like about the return code. Under zsh it doesn't, because `$!` isn't set for process substitutions; that ought to be solvable but I stopped trying. A fixed fifo, rather than a temporary file, would also work here.

In this case you'd probably want to save and restore FD 2 on either side as well.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how "Environment Modules" work, but I'll assume from your description that they're shell functions which set environment variables, and their stderr output should be caught / matched against without running them in a separate process.

The answer, like it or not, is that the only robust and obvious way is to redirect their stderr to a temporary file. Using named pipes is just as unwieldy (you still have to create a temporary file!), in addition to being much trickier. And using co-processes is [onerous, awkward and unportable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86270/how-do-you-use-the-command-coproc-in-various-shells).

In `bash` (and in `bash` only) you can take advantage of an [undocumented feature](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/524844/308316) (`$!` being set to the PID from a `>(...)` process substitution) and get away with something like:

```
module 2> >(grep error)
wait $! && echo failed
```

This example assumes that `module` itself is not spawning any children that may confuse `$!`.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, with both bash and zsh, you should be able to do:

```
my_module() {
  chmod u+w /dev/fd/3 # only needed in bash 5+
  module 2> /dev/fd/3 3>&-
  ! grep -q err /dev/fd/3
} 3<<< ''
```

The `3<<< ''` is a here-string initially containing an empty line. Both `zsh` and `bash` implement here-strings and here-documents as deleted temporary files. On Linux (and Cygwin, but generally not other systems), opening `/dev/fd/3` opens the file pointed to by the fd 3, even if it's already deleted (on other systems, it duplicates fd 3) so it's a very clean way to work with temporary files there. The file is already deleted, you don't have to worry about its cleanup, and it's only visible on the FS for a very short time (since version 5 however, `bash` removes write permissions to it which we need to work around with `chmod`).

Here, you do need a temporary file if you're going to run `module` and `grep` in sequence (as opposed to in parallel in separate processes). Doing it with pipes (like in Michael's approaches, but unlike @mosvy's) would lead to dead-locks if there's enough data output that it fills up the pipes.

Comment: Thank you, that is a neat idea.  What does the `3<<< ''` do?  I figure that it has to do with flusing fd 3 (or something like that), but, if this is the case, I am amazed to find the expression outside the function's definition.

Comment: @kjo, see edit. The syntax of a function definition is `fname() command` (though in the case of bash, that's limited to compound commands). We're used to seeing a command group without redirection as the function body, but it doesn't have to.